# Delegate overwriting

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

If we write some code in any delegate method. would it be some kind of method overloading?

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
    switch (alertView.tag)
    {
    case 1000:
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self revealOneLetter];
        }
        break;
    case 2000:
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self removeSomeLetters];
        }
        break;
    case 5000:
        [self backBtnAction:nil];
        break;
    case 3000:
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self buyBtnAction:nil];
        }
        break;
     }

     }
```

In above code we are calling some methods in delegate methods, so basically we are overwriting the delegate.
What is the exact name for this thing.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. But AFAIK this is not either method overloading or overriding...

Comment: I am agree with @booleanBoy, this is just a normal function call within `UIAlertView` delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *overriding* (or *overwriting* or *overloading*, which are both different) anything, you are *implementing* a delegate method. That is, you are adding a method that can be called by a delegating object. The effect can be similar to overriding a method in a subclass: in both cases, you're modifying the behavior of an object, but the relationships are different. The *delegation* pattern provides *specialization* without subclassing. For example, of the three quarters of a bazillion apps in the app store, approximately all of them use identical UIApplication objects -- nobody subclasses UIApplication because you can specialize it using the application delegate.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the method of a protocol here (the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol) rather than overloading (which I think you meant overwriting).

In objective-C:

- **Overloading** : having the same method name but different parameters doesn't exist (like it does in Java for instance)
- **Overriding** : is the action of rewriting a method in a subclass to adapt the parent behavior in the child context

What you do here is telling the UIAlertView instance how to behave when a certain event occurs (button being clicked)

Answer (score 1):

You're not overwriting anything. You are **implementing** the delegate-protocol.

Overwriting means reimplementing a superclass' method in a subclass. F.e. all those `UIViewController` methods like `viewDidLoad`, when you create your own viewcontroller subclass and write the `viewDidLoad` method, you are **overwriting** the `viewDidLoad` method of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: That's "over*riding*", not "writing".

Answer (score 1):

This is neither *overwriting* nor *overloading*, absolutely not. actually your class (say viewController) **conforming or adopting** to a protocol(in your case `UIAlertViewDelegate`). and in objective-c in **A protocol is a list of method declarations. If your class adopts or conforms the protocol, then you have to implement those methods in your class**. there are two kind of methods in protocol **required** that you have to implement if you are conforming the protocol and other are **optional**, by name you can identify that it is up to developer he want to implement those methods or not.

so in your case your respective class conformed/adopted a protocol i.e `UIAlertViewDelegate` and that's why you are implementing following method which notify you that which button in `UIAlertView` got pressed.

`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`